Can I hide a layer automatically by settings in the layout legend
I always use the same WMTS layer as background map in QGIS. Every time I make a map or update the legend in the Layout Manager I have to manually remove the WMTS layer in the list of layers that I want to show in legend.
Is there a way that I can automatically hide a legend item in a layout legend by certain layer settings?

Please add details on how you create the legend.

I got template QGIS file that I use on a regulary base. In this file there are certain Map themes; a couple of vector layers and a WMTS background map. On a regulary base these Map themes changes, therefore I update the legend (automatically update: on) en then the WMTS is back in the legend.

Is this WMTS layer enabled when exporting the map?

The WMTS is enabled and showed in the map because it's the background map.
